# Creating Apple passbook webservice on linux without using XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, passbook

I am able to make web pages that sign and create apple Passes for Passbook.  The last thing I need to do is make the webservice, which allows the pass to check if it has changed or updated.  If you define a webservice link in your pass's JSON it will query the location with RESTful get/delete commands.

I have never done RESTful things, so I looked for examples to dissect and implement.  These are two notable ones below that I have tried - 
https://github.com/ole/Kaffeekasse 
https://github.com/tribbettz/passbook_rails_example

I don't know ruby either but that's not the problem, I tried installing both of them and they require xCode to proceed installation.  xCode is Mac only and I am using linux.  I am not sure why XCode is required.  Apple documentation has no mentioning of needing it.  I have a Mac for creating certificates but not a mac server.  I asked the creator of Kaffeekasse if you need xCode for the webservice and he said no, but wouldn't explain why. This is a problem because it might suggest I need a Mac server just for this, because I don't see any non-xCode examples.

There is little documentation regarding passbook webservice and I am trying to host it on my own rather than pay a pass service provider that handles everything when I just need an update service.

Comment: The Kaffeekasse Tutorial only uses XCode to create the iOS app, nothing more: " We will use Xcode later to build the iOS app. We require the command line tools to have a working Git installation, so if you have installed Git from another source, you can omit this step."

Comment: It helps to have a Mac and Xcode for debugging, but it is entirely possible to run the entire web service on a Linux box. We use our own privately developed Golang packages to provide the web service and to compile and serve .pkpass bundles but there are also plenty of public PHP libraries that you could run behind an Apache server if your volumes are not so significant. The most challenging part is tracking devices against the passes that they are holding.  For that, then looking at Apple's ruby sample SQLite schema would be a good place to start.

Comment: I disagree. I think Apple's documentation is pretty comprehensive when it comes to their web service for Passbook. I implemented a simple service using their documentation and .Net. You can see it on Github (dotnet-passbook) so I know it's possible.